# Reading sound files from jar file

Tags: java, audio, jar

So I've been making a game, and have decided that I want to a sound effects for it. I can play sounds just fine until I package the class files and (and the wav  audio files) the into the jar, and only to find that it can't find the files. I am using `getClass().getResource("sounds/enemyExplode.wav")` to get the file. Is there a different method that I should be using? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sounds` folder should be placed inside `src` folder.

Comment: Are the wav files in the jar itself?

Comment: `getClass().getResource()` accepts a relative path (to the package) and requires a leading `/` if you want an "absolute" path (within the JAR, that is)

Comment: Define "can't find the files" and post your code; what happens, exactly? Also, Where in the .jar are your sound files?

Comment: I will try the beginning / and see if works out. Thank you. And the wav files are in the jar in /sounds/.

Comment: I am using a prebuilt class for playing my sounds [link](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml) and I don't know what is going on in that file. I am using the constructor `code`new AePlayWave(getClass().getResource("/sounds/enemyExplode.wav").toString().split(":")[2]).start();`code`

`code`getClass().getResource("/sounds/enemyExplode.wav").toString().split(":")[1]`code` gets the URI to the file, then turns it into a string, then splits it at the ":" after file because the Class I'm using doesn't like having it there, and then it returns the second part

Answer (score 3):

The class loader's **getResource()** method operates on resources within the class path. If you have the sounds at the following location in the JAR:

```
/sounds/enemyExplode.wav
```

Then you need to use a leading slash in front of the path (just as above) in that call.

Remember a JAR file is really nothing more than a packaged up version of the filesystem (same format as a zip) and the class loader operates upon it as it would if it were a filesystem.

Comment: The sound files are in the jar file, and I am using the slash at the front of the file

Answer (score 3):

Within a jar, I've learned it works better to use getResourceAsStream(). If you are using AudioInputStream then it works just as well:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream
(Sound.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

And this is how the file name should look (soundbase, is in your case "sounds"):

```
"/" + soundbase + "/" + file.wav
```

I have a fully functioning sound class that I found online some place a few years ago that works quite well. I slightly modified it, but it should work in most scenarios if you want me to post it.

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure your sounds are actually packaged in the jar file. you can open the jar file with any archiver that supports zip.

secondly, when you call `blabla.getClass().getResources("sounds")` you operate relative to the class path of blabla, that means that the full package name in which blabla is contained will be prepended to "sound" to resolve the full path inside the jar file.

if you want to specify an absolute path , just prepend a slash to the path: `blabla.getClass().getResources("/sound")`

Comment: The sound files are in the jar file, and I am using the slash at the front of the file